Why are my HTML table elements not correctly sized?
I am working on a version of Wordle that has you balance a chemistry equation, and for the sort of keyboard down at the bottom, I am using a table. However, each element within the table is a different size, even though in the CSS I have set the width to be a specific amount. I thought it was due to the fact that the text was larger on some boxes, and so I tried decreasing the size of the text to see if that made a difference, but it didn't. I'm not entirely sure where to go from here. I have also tried changing the padding values and the margins, but nothing seems to work. The only progress I got was when I made the font size 1 pixel, they were all the same size except for the end ones. Here is the code for the table and the CSS styling.
Note: I'm not actually sure if the filler class is necessary, but when I was trying to offset the second row I tried using a different width, and just left it in.


.answer {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.option {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: light-stories;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.filler {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
<table class="answer">
  <tr>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">CN<sup>-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">OH<sup>-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">ClO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">ClO<sub>2</sub><sup>-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">ClO<sup>-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2-</sup></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filler"></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">HCO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">PO<sub>4</sub><sup>3-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">SO<sub>3</sub><sup>2-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NO<sub>2</sub><sup>-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">MnO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">PO<sub>3</sub><sup>3-</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">
      C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>3</sub>O<sub>2</sub><sup>-</sup>
    </td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">
      C<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>
    </td>
    <td class="filler"></td>
  </tr>
</table>




Even the shortest cell contents you got there, do no appear to fit into a width of 25px. So why are you trying to specify 25px then?

If your goal is to make the boxes 25px in width, how do you want to handle the text overflow within them?

Because you have a 1-column shift and your filled cells all span 2 columns you introduce flexibility that is related to cell content. Forced widths aren't always respected, so you get what we see here.
If you were to standardize cell content you'd see cells that are all the same size, except the last one, but you can see in the horizontal shift that they're not centered on the split between columns. This is why the last filled cell is short.
This is just the nature of auto-sized tables. I suggest that you switch to a CSS grid layout so you have more control. If accessibility is a concern see Grid layout and accessibility.


.answer {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.option {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: light-stories;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.filler {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
<table class="answer">
  <tr>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filler"></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="option" colspan="2">NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup></td>
    <td class="filler"></td>
  </tr>
</table>



